# What is the difference between git fetch and git fetch origin

Tags: git, gitlab

What is the difference between these two commands?

```
git fetch
```

and

```
git fetch origin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler than the linked answer (which is really about what name(s) are updated with `git fetch origin` vs `git fetch origin master` vs `git fetch origin master:master`; and that answer is slightly different for very old versions of Git as its behavior changed a bit in Git version 1.8.4).

To quote [the `git fetch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

> When no remote is specified, by default the `origin` remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch.

In other words:

```
git fetch
```

is *exactly the same* as:

```
git fetch origin
```

*unless* the current branch has an upstream setting that refers to a remote other than `origin`.  So if, for instance, the current branch is `rumpelsnakeskin` and the upstream of `rumpelsnakeskin` is `habitat/rumpelsnakeskin`, then `git fetch` means `git fetch habitat`.  But if the current branch is, say, `master` and its upstream is `origin/master` or is not set at all, then `git fetch` means `git fetch origin`.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` fetch the whole all remotes.
but in `git fetch origin` by using `origin` you specify the `remote` which need to be fetched

[see this for reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Comment: That's not correct.  You can use `git fetch --all` to fetch all remotes, or you can use `git remote update` and/or remote groups.

Comment: thanks for the clarification